# python Outlier Nutri function

Tags: python

Hi I have to create a function that applies the function "**delete_outliers**" on all columns.

First of all my data is :

```
pnns_groups_1     ................................  object

pnns_groups_2     ................................  object

proteins_100g     ................................  float64

fiber_100g        ................................  float64

salt_100g         ................................  float64

fat_100g          ................................  float64

trans-fat_100g    ................................  float64

carbohydrates_100g ................................  float64

sugars_100g  ................................  float64

starch_100g  ................................  float64

omega-3-fat_100g ................................  float64

nutrition_grade_fr ................................  float64

nutrition-score-fr_100g  ................................  float64

energy_100g   ................................  float64
```

dtype: object

I created this function :

```
*def delete_outliers(col):*

    inf = (col.quantile(0.25)-(1.5* (col.quantile(0.75)-col.quantile(0.25))))
    sup = (col.quantile(0.75)+(1.5*(col.quantile(0.75)-col.quantile(0.25))))
    return col.between(inf,sup)*col
```

I can not apply the **detect_outlier** function on all my dataframe, even when I remove **pnns_groups_1** and **pnns_groups_2** from my dataframe, to keep only **float64** data

I had an attribute error :

> `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'between'`

Comment: between is Series method, are you sure you pass col as single column and not as DataFrame?

Comment: @G.M looks like you are passing DataFrame object instead of column to detect_outliers, make sure you pass column to same function

Comment: @michal Polovka, I do not see how to put "col" in single column.
I tried "dataframe.values" but it takes me the values online and not in column.
For information I have '320571' rows and '12' columns.
How do I do to execute my function on the 12 columns? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most probably passing DataFrame instead of just column to your function.
To apply your function to several columns, use

```
result = df.apply(delete_outliers, axis=0)
```

This will apply your function to every column (you can use slices) and return the result in form of DataFrame.

For full method reference consult [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)